# New Apache setup sent email isn't always received - PHP Mail() - Sendmail

Tags: apache, email, dns, sendmail, spf

I recently purchased a cloud VPS service.

I've configured my website everything on that front is fine and well, however I noticed email isn't always being received.

Having inspected the log at: /var/log/maillog

I can see the following:

```
Sep 10 21:59:01 mail sendmail[2615]: u8AKx0ZK002614: to=root, ctladdr=<apache@mywebsitedomain.co.uk> (48/48), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=41036, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2656]: u8AL3G7U002656: from=apache, size=10690, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<015be58bc4d8990a25ba7895538ea4db@mywebsitedomain.co.uk>, relay=apache@localhost
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2657]: u8AL3G7h002657: from=<apache@mywebsitedomain.co.uk>, size=10783, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<015be58bc4d8990a25ba7895538ea4db@mywebsitedomain.co.uk>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mywebsitedomain.co.uk [127.0.0.1]
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2656]: u8AL3G7U002656: to=info@mywebsitedomain.co.uk, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=40690, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u8AL3G7h002657 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2658]: u8AL3G7h002657: to=root, ctladdr=<apache@mywebsitedomain.co.uk> (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=40996, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2660]: u8AL3GQp002660: from=apache, size=10914, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<d148a9c441d201d8a24c64c517050ede@mywebsitedomain.co.uk>, relay=apache@localhost
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2661]: u8AL3GB4002661: from=<apache@mywebsitedomain.co.uk>, size=11007, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<d148a9c441d201d8a24c64c517050ede@mywebsitedomain.co.uk>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mywebsitedomain.co.uk [127.0.0.1]
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2660]: u8AL3GQp002660: to=mypersonalemail@googlemail.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=40914, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u8AL3GB4002661 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 10 22:03:16 mail sendmail[2663]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Sep 10 22:03:17 mail sendmail[2663]: u8AL3GB4002661: to=<mypersonalemail@googlemail.com>, ctladdr=<apache@mywebsitedomain.co.uk> (48/48), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=131007, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [64.233.166.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1473541397 f23si8646501wmh.115 - gsmtp)
```

The email is successfully received on my personal Google email address, but the other order confirmation isn't received on the business email side (which is hosted by Google Apps)

I can also see for some reason the email apache@mywebsitedomain.co.uk is being used... When really I guess this should be info?

Could this be the reason I am not receiving emails or am I missing the plot here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as always!

**EDIT**

I tried the contact form again and this now no longer works, I have a feeling because I haven't changed my live DNS of the domain to the new server. Google feels I may be spoofing the email address? But I did alter the SPF record to include the new server IP (would this not be enough?)

Comment: You tagged as php, why? There's no code to support the question, just a log.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, the email is being produced by a Wordpress website. Should I untag it? I'm not sure if the website might be the culprit? Then again it hasn't produced any errors on the other server it was on which was actually a Windows IIS. I've removed this now :)

Comment: It could be a headers issue. Then again, if you don't have an SPF record, then that may be why.  Have a look at this article on the subject, that another (Stack) member posted lately http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/04/spf-dkim-and-dmarc-brief-explanation.html - I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Fred, I have altered my SPF and setup DKIM authentication. The business email does receive email fine through the contact form if that helps?

Comment: It's hard to say and it could be anything really. I take it you're using PHP's `mail()` function. You could try using either phpmailer or swiftmailer. Many have had great results after switching over to those. Check for possible errors also with error reporting, see if anything comes of it. It probably won't, but let's not leave it out of the equation. If it's a malformed header somewhere in your code, than that could also contribute to the problem. That's about the scope of my knowledge on this one.

Comment: Honestly I'm using Woocommerce (which is a Wordpress plugin) which generates the order confirmation emails itself. I really don't want to mess around with that stuff (especially the state I'm in at the moment haha). My bet is it is a server configuration issue as I had to install everything from scratch on the barebones Linux server. I must have missed something!

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by simply installing and switching to postfix (Credit to Rocket_Doge_) for helping me with this!